# Unable to get data from an interface inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, interface, fragment

I have implemented a custom interface for passing data like below:

```
public interface OnLectureSelected {
    public void lectureSelected(String videoId,String lectureDescription);
}
```

in the adapter, I am then using the interface to pass data to the activity & the fragment:

```
OnLectureSelected onLectureSelected2 = (OnLectureSelected) context;
onLectureSelected2.lectureSelected(video,description);
```

The **activity is able** to receive the data as expected:

```
class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnLectureSelected{
  …
 @Override
 public void lectureSelected(String videoId, String lectureDescription) {
  //I get the passed details
 }
```

However, I am unable to get the data using a fragment:

```
class Fragment extends Fragment implements OnLectureSelected{
  …
 @Override
 public void lectureSelected(String videoId, String lectureDescription) {
  //Can't get the passed details
 }
```

What is the best approach to get the data from the interface inside the fragment?

Comment: get the data from interface means? are you not getting method declared in OnLectureSelected?

Comment: and what is the purpose to declare class somthing like this class Fragment extends Fragment ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OnLectureSelected onLectureSelected2 = (OnLectureSelected) context;
```

Here this object will pass the value to only one implemented class. To pass the value to fragments you can call the below method in your `Activity` class

```
@Override
    public void lectureSelected(String videoId, String lectureDescription) {
        //Can't get the passed details
        List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        if (fragments != null) {
            for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
                if(fragment instanceof FragmentClasas) {
                    fragment.lectureSelected(video,description);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```